# sqoop data from teradata to hdfs using shell script

Tags: sqoop

Getting below exception.

What are the possible errors?

Is it really database does not exist? or related to Permission related issue?

```
com.teradata.connector.common.exception.ConnectorException: java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.00.00.20] [Error 3802] [SQLState 42S02] Database 'P_STORAGE' does not exist.
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDatabaseSQLException(ErrorFactory.java:308)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.ReceiveInitSubState.action(ReceiveInitSubState.java:109)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.subStateMachine(StatementReceiveState.java:307)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.action(StatementReceiveState.java:196)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementController.runBody(StatementController.java:123)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementController.run(StatementController.java:114)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.executeStatement(TDStatement.java:385)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.prepareRequest(TDStatement.java:569)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDPreparedStatement.<init>(TDPreparedStatement.java:117)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6_SQL_PreparedStatement.<init>(JDK6_SQL_PreparedStatement.java:29)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6_SQL_Connection.constructPreparedStatement(JDK6_SQL_Connection.java:81)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDSession.prepareStatement(TDSession.java:1357)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDSession.prepareStatement(TDSession.java:1401)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDSession.prepareStatement(TDSession.java:1387)
        at com.teradata.connector.teradata.db.TeradataConnection.getColumnDescsForSQL(TeradataConnection.java:995)
        at com.teradata.connector.teradata.db.TeradataConnection.getColumnNamesForSQL(TeradataConnection.java:940)
        at com.teradata.connector.teradata.utils.TeradataUtils.validateInputTeradataProperties(TeradataUtils.java:315)
        at com.teradata.connector.teradata.processor.TeradataInputProcessor.validateConfiguration(TeradataInputProcessor.java:91)
        at com.teradata.connector.teradata.processor.TeradataSplitByPartitionProcessor.validateConfiguration(TeradataSplitByPartitionProcessor.java:412)
        at com.teradata.connector.teradata.processor.TeradataInputProcessor.inputPreProcessor(TeradataInputProcessor.java:36)
        at com.teradata.connector.common.tool.ConnectorJobRunner.runJob(ConnectorJobRunner.java:116)
        at com.teradata.connector.common.tool.ConnectorJobRunner.runJob(ConnectorJobRunner.java:56)
        at org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataSqoopImportHelper.runJob(TeradataSqoopImportHelper.java:370)
        at org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager.importQuery(TeradataConnManager.java:531)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:499)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:148)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:184)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:226)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:235)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:244)

        at com.teradata.connector.common.tool.ConnectorJobRunner.runJob(ConnectorJobRunner.java:140)
        at com.teradata.connector.common.tool.ConnectorJobRunner.runJob(ConnectorJobRunner.java:56)
        at org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataSqoopImportHelper.runJob(TeradataSqoopImportHelper.java:370)
        at org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager.importQuery(TeradataConnManager.java:531)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:499)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:148)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:184)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:226)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:235)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:244)
16/09/23 05:47:10 INFO teradata.TeradataSqoopImportHelper: Teradata import job completed with exit code 1
16/09/23 05:47:10 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Exception running Teradata import job
        at org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataSqoopImportHelper.runJob(TeradataSqoopImportHelper.java:373)
        at org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager.importQuery(TeradataConnManager.java:531)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:499)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:148)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:184)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:226)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:235)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:244)
Caused by: com.teradata.connector.common.exception.ConnectorException: java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.00.00.20] [Error 3802] [SQLState 42S02] Database 'P_STORAGE' does not exist.
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDatabaseSQLException(ErrorFactory.java:308)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.ReceiveInitSubState.action(ReceiveInitSubState.java:109)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.subStateMachine(StatementReceiveState.java:307)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.action(StatementReceiveState.java:196)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementController.runBody(StatementController.java:123)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementController.run(StatementController.java:114)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.executeStatement(TDStatement.java:385)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.prepareRequest(TDStatement.java:569)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDPreparedStatement.<init>(TDPreparedStatement.java:117)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6_SQL_PreparedStatement.<init>(JDK6_SQL_PreparedStatement.java:29)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6_SQL_Connection.constructPreparedStatement(JDK6_SQL_Connection.java:81)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDSession.prepareStatement(TDSession.java:1357)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDSession.prepareStatement(TDSession.java:1401)
        at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDSession.prepareStatement(TDSession.java:1387)
        at com.teradata.connector.teradata.db.TeradataConnection.getColumnDescsForSQL(TeradataConnection.java:995)
        at com.teradata.connector.teradata.db.TeradataConnection.getColumnNamesForSQL(TeradataConnection.java:940)
        at com.teradata.connector.teradata.utils.TeradataUtils.validateInputTeradataProperties(TeradataUtils.java:315)
        at com.teradata.connector.teradata.processor.TeradataInputProcessor.validateConfiguration(TeradataInputProcessor.java:91)
        at com.teradata.connector.teradata.processor.TeradataSplitByPartitionProcessor.validateConfiguration(TeradataSplitByPartitionProcessor.java:412)
        at com.teradata.connector.teradata.processor.TeradataInputProcessor.inputPreProcessor(TeradataInputProcessor.java:36)
        at com.teradata.connector.common.tool.ConnectorJobRunner.runJob(ConnectorJobRunner.java:116)
        at com.teradata.connector.common.tool.ConnectorJobRunner.runJob(ConnectorJobRunner.java:56)
        at org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataSqoopImportHelper.runJob(TeradataSqoopImportHelper.java:370)
        at org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager.importQuery(TeradataConnManager.java:531)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:499)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:148)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:184)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:226)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:235)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:244)

        at com.teradata.connector.common.tool.ConnectorJobRunner.runJob(ConnectorJobRunner.java:140)
        at com.teradata.connector.common.tool.ConnectorJobRunner.runJob(ConnectorJobRunner.java:56)
        at org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataSqoopImportHelper.runJob(TeradataSqoopImportHelper.java:370)
        ... 9 more
```

Comment: use sqoop list-databases command and see whether database really exists.

Answer (score 0):

It could be either issue.

Please try `sqoop eval` with the same credentials:

```
sqoop eval --connect "<teradata connect class param>" \
--username <username> -P
--query "SELECT * FROM DBC.Databases"
```